# Correct way to export batches of XML to PDF using Crystal Reports?

Tags: asp.net, xml, crystal-reports, pdf-generation

I have the following function which is ran inside a loop, on every xml file in a specified directory:

```
 Public Function createReport(ByVal rptName As String, ByVal pdfName As String, ByVal xmlInput As String) As String

        Dim ds As New DataSet
        Dim cr As New ReportDocument
        Dim CRfile As String = crystalFilePath & rptName & "Template.rpt"
        ds.ReadXml(xmlInput)

        cr.FileName = CRfile
        cr.DataSourceConnections.Clear()

        cr.SetDataSource(ds)
        cr.Refresh()
        cr.VerifyDatabase()

        Dim pdfPath As String = outputDirectory & rptName & "\pdf\" & pdfName & ".pdf"

        Try
            cr.ExportToDisk(ExportFormatType.PortableDocFormat, pdfPath)
        Catch ex As Exception
            If Not ex.InnerException Is Nothing Then
                Return pdfName & "<br /> <strong>Error:</strong> " & ex.InnerException.ToString
            Else
                Return pdfName & "<br /> <strong>Error:</strong> Unknown error (no inner exception text)"
            End If

        End Try

        cr.Close()
        cr.Dispose()
        GC.Collect()


        Return "Success"

    End Function
```

Sometimes I get hit with the error

> The maximum report processing jobs limit configured by your system administrator has been reached

I suspect I am not correctly disposing of memory in each iteration?

Answer (score 0):

This error is meant to help developers and users know when they are putting a high reporting load on the server that runs the report.  I recommend reading this [blog post](http://toniyojackson.blogspot.com/2010/09/maximum-report-processing-jobs-limit.html) for some ideas on how to resolve your error.

By default there is a limit of 75 report print jobs.  Bear in mind that subreports placed inside your main report count towards this limit.  So a single print of a report with 4 subreports will count as 5 prints towards the limit.  There is a registry edit that can be used to increase this limit, but the machine running the report may suffer from performance issues if you increase the limit.  In the past I've encountered out of memory errors as a direct result of setting the limit too high for the machine running the reports.

This blog also discusses some coding practices you can follow to clean up objects and temp files in ways that may help you solve your problem.  I recommend exhausting all of the coding practices first before trying the registry edit solution.

Comment: After getting this error I try again using just 1 single report and still receive it... leads me to believe there is an issue cleaning up the old ones.

Additionally, neither Business Objects or Crystal Decisions exists under HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\

Comment: You may want to focus on cleaning up temp files first then.  Crystal Reports temp files are found in your user folder's `AppData\Local\Temp` directory.  The full path can vary depending on your OS, but in Windows 10 the default should be at `C:\Users\[username]\AppData\Local\Temp`.